# nodejs vs. ruby / understanding requests processing order

Tags: node.js, ruby, image-processing, concurrency

I have a simple utility that i use to size image on the fly via url params.
Having some troubles with the ruby image libraries (cmyk to rvb is, how to say… "unavailable"), i gave it a shot via nodejs, which solved the issue.

Basically, if the image does not exists, node or ruby transforms it. Otherwise when the image has already been requested/transformed, the ruby or node processes aren't touched, the image is returned statically

The ruby works perfectly, a bit slow if lot of transforms are requested at once, but very stable, it always go through whatever the amount (i see the images arriving one the page one after another)

With node, it works also perfectly, but when a large amount of images are requested, for a single page load, the first images is transformed, then all the others requests returns the very same image (the last transformed one). If I refresh the page, the first images (already transformed) is returned right away, the second one is returned correctly transformed, but then all the other images returned are the same as the one just newly transformed. and it goes on the same for every refresh. not optimal , basically the resquests are "merged" at some point and all return the same image. for reason i don't understand

(When using 'large amount', i mean more than 1)

The ruby version :

```
get "/:commands/*" do |commands,remote_path|
    path          = "./public/#{commands}/#{remote_path}"
    root_domain   = request.host.split(/\./).last(2).join(".")
    url           = "https://storage.googleapis.com/thebucket/store/#{remote_path}"
    img           = Dragonfly.app.fetch_url(url)
    resized_img   = img.thumb(commands).to_response(env)
    return resized_img
end
```

The node js version :

```
app.get('/:transform/:id', function(req,res,next){
  parser.parse(req.params,function(resized_img){
    // the transform are done via lovell/sharp
    // parser.parse parse the params, write the file,
    // return the file path
    // then :
    fs.readFileSync(resized_img, function(error,data){
      res.write(data)
      res.end()
    })
  })
})
```

Feels like I'm missing here a crucial point in node. I expected the same behaviour with node and ruby, but obviously the same pattern transposed in the node area just does not work as expected. Node is not waiting for a request to process, rather processes those somehow in an order that is not clear to me

I also understand that i'm not putting the right words to describe the issue, hoping that it might speak to some experienced users, let them provide clarifiactions to get a better understanding of what happens behind the node scenes

Comment: What's the point of this: let protocol = getProtocol(req)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code.  If it works one image at a time or small batches, I would suspect the parser.parse.  I would try adding a log item like this:
     log( req.params, resized_img, hash(data) )

before the res.write statement and see if that reveals anything

Comment: ` let protocol` was irrelevant here in the example you're right. I use `async.waterfall` in parser.parse, it only returns when the file is actually transformed and saved; i kind of trust it so far. would there be a better way to reinforce and ensure things are returned correctly for each requests ? I just don't see why at some point, it can return the same image for every requests made. thx for your hints, i will double check that way anyhow

Comment: No - the only suspect would be some sort of shared memory that is getting reused at load.

Comment: solved it. using sharp, i had the `toFile` method in `parser.parse`, then using `readFileSync` to return it to the client. Taking back the `toFile` method to the main app.get() context, and using request to pipe the output (rather than using `readFileSync`), things started to work a expected. problem is, i just don't understand why the first one not working; which was more or less the bottom of my question